# Why using NOT LIKE for one column in MySQL filters results for rows where column is empty?

Tags: mysql, sql

When I use this query:

```
SELECT `visitors`.`id`, `visitors`.`ip`, `visitors`.`url`, `visitors`.`time`, `visitors`.`agent`, `visitors`.`reference`
FROM (`visitors`)
WHERE  `reference` NOT LIKE '%bot%'
ORDER BY `id` desc
LIMIT 2000
```

In the results I can't see rows where the `reference` column is empty. What should I do to create a result set with empty reference columns?

Comment: empty columns, "null-columns" are special. They are neither equal or non-equal to any other values. The only way to check for them are, as X.L.Ant says, to use <col> is null / not <col> is null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try :

```
SELECT `visitors`.`id`, `visitors`.`ip`, `visitors`.`url`, `visitors`.`time`, `visitors`.`agent`, `visitors`.`reference`
FROM (`visitors`)
WHERE  `reference` NOT LIKE '%bot%' OR `reference` IS NULL
ORDER BY `id` desc
LIMIT 2000
```

`NULL` is not handled the same way as an empty value.

Comment: using or will kill the performence. is there any other suggestion ?

Comment: @motto - Kill is a strong word, why do you believe the performance would suffer?

Comment: No. - there are no other ways.

Comment: If the reference column is reasonably indexed, the LIKE will be a much largher performance hit than the OR.

Comment: Everything is said in other comments, nothing to add :)

Comment: Using wild cards at both ends of 'bot' will preclude the use of an index on that column. That is far more likely to "kill performance".

Comment: In other words, the performance has already been killed enough, there's nothing left for the OR to kill. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an explicit condition to get the columns that are null.

```
select visitors.id, visitors.ip, visitors.url, visitors.time, visitors.agent, visitors.reference
from visitors
where reference not like '%bot%' or reference is null
order by id desc
limit 2000;
```